# Fluid layout with fixed gutter

Tags: susy-compass

I was really inspired by the layout of this site http://sassandcompass.com/ which is said to be using Susy and I want to make the layout for my new website with the same idea. What I want to have is a layout which spans fully across the browser width but also at the same time stays responsive. I used 'fluid' container style in Susy but I don't know how to maintain the fixed gutter width. Here is my settings:

```
   $total-columns: 4; 

   $column-width: 4em;

   $gutter-width: 1em;

   $container-style: fluid;

   $tablet: 8;

   $desktop: 12;
```

Could you please tell me what's wrong with my settings and what possible settings that site is using?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The site you linked to does not maintain a fixed gutter width. Susy 1 doesn't have any support for that, but Susy 2 (currently in alpha) does. You might be able to fake it in Susy 1 by setting gutters to `0`, applying `border-box` box-sizing to all your grid elements, and then adding you gutters manually as padding.

Comment: Thank you Eric for your swift reply! Do you know what container style that site is using, fluid or magic? Regarding the layout I want to make (e.g, spanning the whole page width but still responsive), are my settings above ok?

Comment: Since they have `max-width: 73em;` on their container (`.inner-content`), I'd say they are using the default "magic" setting. But for what you want, your settings above are great.

Comment: I didn't know that there is a section to download the sample code on the site and it's exactly using magic layout as you said. Thanks a lot Eric!